# Intellij documentation pop up does not work properly

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

Despite that I have ticked the "auto-display documentation" and tried inputting different numbers in "ms" box - I still have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to see the documentation. How to make it work?
[image: not showing documentation]
[image: box ticked]

Also if I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to show documentation pop up manually - the pop up is too small. Can I make it bigger by default to contain all the text? 

[image: documentation pop up - too small]

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Ultimate Edition) Build #UI-181.4203.550 
Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia, Cinnamon 64-bit

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want this setting:

**`Settings`** > **`Editor`** > **`General`**

> **`Show quick documentation on mouse move`**

And to make the **documentation pop-up text larger**:

- Click the gear icon in the top-right corner of the pop-up, there is a setting there.

[image]

Comment: this was bugging me for so long! Wish I'd found this 2 months earlier

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a bug. If you open the settings via the gear icon and tick the `show toolbar` it will work again (at least I was able to reproduce it and this fixed it for me).

I don't have issues with the size (I'm on mac) using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-181.4668.14.

You can create an issue on their issue tracker here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

For more info about reporting issues, see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reporting-issues.html

Update for IntelliJ 2018.2:

> The code completion in IntelliJ IDEA continues to evolve, and now the IDE shows both all the possible auto-completions and Javadoc, at the same time (without the need to directly invoke Javadoc each time). Please be aware that you need to actually enable this cool new feature. Go to Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion and turn on the Show the documentation info pop-up in… options.

[image: screenshot of the feature in action]
[image: screenshot of the settings]

(more info here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/05/intellij-idea-2018-2-early-access-program-is-open)

Comment: Clicking "Open as Tool Window" made it start working for me, and then switching back to the popup, it was working! Thank you. I'm on Pop!_OS 20.10 with GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

The above-mentioned solutions are different in version 2023.x. To enable quick documentation on mouse hover, go to "**Settings -> Editor -> Code Editing -> Quick Documentation -> Show quick documentation on hover**" and enable this checkbox.

Also at the end of this section, is another option to control the delay: "**Editor Tooltips -> Tooltip Delay**"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the documentation was not downloaded, so I have manually downloaded it. Right-click on the `pom.xml` file and choose
[image: pom options]